# Changing a preset in ACCPAC Pro Series 6.0

Tags: sbt, accpac

I'm trying to change a preset in the Accounts Receivable section of ACCPAC Pro Series 6.0 (accounting software). I'm looking for the file, I think it's with a .prg extension, that would hold any preset information for the Accounts Receivable module within the program.

When posting a receipt of a payment, there is an area, "Check/Ref" where you can enter either a reference number for a check or a preset credit card type.

I would like to ADD a preset credit card type.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to which file would hold that info so I can make the change?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've been a developer for Pro Series 5 and 7.  I am not familiar with 6.  I will say that there isn't necessarily a single location for what you describe; and it is entirely possible that it may require changes to *data* rather than a *program*.

In order to do this correctly, you would need to give the name of the form, and the exact name of the field.  Also, you need to indicate if this is strictly Pro Series 6, or a version that has been modified by a VAR.

Answer (score -1):

o yes. Accpac Pro Series, previously known as SBT. It's FoxPro application and you need help from FoxPro Developer to do that.